# Binding data to the Listbox where ListBox has textblocks

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, wpf-controls

```xml
<ListBox Height="498" Margin="2,0,0,0" Name="listBox1" Width="879"  ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
   <ListBoxItem >
       <StackPanel Width="418" Orientation="Horizontal">
           <TextBlock Name="MedicineName" Text="Alamoxy" 
                      FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="18" 
                      Margin="5" Width="205" >
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Name="ListBoxLetter" Text="Amoksilin" 
                       FontSize="18" Margin="0" Width="255" Height="23">
            </TextBlock>
       </StackPanel>
    </ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

I want to bind data to the listbox.
Textblock will show seprate fields. How i can do it?
please Help me about this/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [ItemTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) to make it look something like this.

```
<ListBox Width="400" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding myItems}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <StackPanel>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MedicineName}" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ListBoxLetter}"/>
       </StackPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```